# preg_match to find specific string followed by arbitrary numbers

Tags: regex

I have the HTML markup of a web page as $subject. I'm using preg_match to search for a particular string ***artist_x?*** and trying to return just the x portion. x can be any number ranging from 1 to 12 digits. So, the pattern would have to match any/all of the following:

```
artist_1?
artist_12345?
artist_123456789012?
```

...and bring back:

```
1
12345
123456789012
```

...respectively.

This is the closest I can come up with:

```
$pattern = '|[artist_][0-9]{1,12}|';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

But it's not working right... It's finding the string I'm looking for and even returning the expected number, but the returned number still has the underscore prepended. I've tried quite a few solutions to get this far, but am out of ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what your pattern is supposed to do.
Anyway, this should work: you just capture the number that interest you. `$matches` will be an array containing first the whole match and then the group. So the first group will be what you want.

```
$subject = "artist_3333";
$pattern = '/artist_(\d{1,12})/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo($matches[1]); // 3333
```

`\d` in here means the same thing as `[0-9]`, it matches digits

Comment: Instead of `+`, use `{1,12}` for the digits, since OP has specified the possible lengths

Comment: It works great on my localhost with those 4 lines you posted, but it's not working in context. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using PHP's file_get_contents to get the markup from the [page](https://www.reverbnation.com/imaginedragons), but when I print_r on $matches, it's an empty array.

Comment: Oops sorry, I added `^` at the beginning which will only match the beginning of a string. Remove it from the pattern and it should be ok

Comment: Aha! It's working perfectly...thanks so much! I'm new, so my upvote doesn't count publicly (I think) but I did upvote your answer.